# Как привязать окно пользователя к концу страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как привязать окно пользователя к концу страницы, без анимаций (они слишком долгие, даже если 1 ms сделать в animate(scrollTop)), чтобы логи, которые я вывожу при помощи jquery, видел пользователь

```
$('#container').html(html);
```

чтобы выглядело примерно как в консольке, когда идет лог, автоматически перелистывается страничка вниз без анимаций и тп

Comment: Если анимация не планируется, то один из возможных вариантов: `$('#container').scrollTop(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);`.

Comment: а есть какой-нибудь метод, чтобы сразу привязать расположение, без скролов

Comment: Нет, такой магии не встречал. В конечном счете, всё будет замыкаться на scroll

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, что вам скроллбар справа не нужен?

Comment: нужно следать так, чтобы при добавлении контента, пользователь видел только то, снизу блока

Comment: Полоса прокрутки справа пользователю нужна или нет? У него должна быть возможность прокрутить выше?

Comment: да, если он прокрутил чуток вверх, значит, автоскролл не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если без анимации, то прокручиваем вниз так:

```js
$('#container').scrollTop(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
```

Или без jQuery:

```js
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight
```

Этого достаточно, чтобы реализовать любую логику работы с консолью. Например, так:

```js
add.onclick = (e) => {
  let tolerance = 10;
  let bottomPos = cons.scrollHeight - cons.clientHeight - cons.scrollTop;
  cons.innerHTML += '<div>message ' + Math.random() + '</div>';

  if (bottomPos < tolerance)
    cons.scrollTop = cons.scrollHeight;
};
```

```css
#cons {
  width: 500px;
  height: 145px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="cons"></div>
<button id="add">Добавить</div>
```

Пользователь можно спокойно прокручивать историю, и ему ничего не будет мешать. Если пользователь прокрутит вниз, то контент будет автоматически скролиться с учетом tolerance.

Если без скролов, можно привязать абсолютно позиционированный дочерний блок к нижней части окна:

```js
add.onclick = (e) => {
  content.innerHTML += '<div>message ' + Math.random() + '</div>';
};
```

```css
#console {
  width: 500px;
  height: 145px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="console">
  <div id="content"></div>    
</div>
<button id="add">Добавить</div>
```

Но в этом случае, нет полосы прокрутки справа.
Если она все-таки нужна, то можно применить хитрость. Мы переворачиваем вверх ногами окно и тоже самое делаем с вложенным блоком:

```js
add.onclick = (e) => {
  content.innerHTML += '<div>message ' + Math.random() + '</div>';
};
```

```css
#console {
  width: 500px;
  height: 145px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}

#content {
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div id="console">
  <div id="content"></div>    
</div>
<button id="add">Добавить</div>
```

При добавлении данных прокрутка будет держаться. Но это извращение, колёсико мышки будет работать в реверсе. Поэтому используйте первый вариант и будет счастье.

Comment: спасибо огромное, гений

Comment: еще если в css к тегу html добавить стиль

scroll-behavior: inherit !important;
тгда он будет мгновенным